# Perfomance profiler attached to C++/CLI dll doesn't reach native C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, profiler

Setup:

In a C# program i call functions from a .NET C++/CLI dll.
This dll has static linking with a native C++ library. Visual Studio 2017 is the envoirement.

Settings:

- Both projects have Debug Information Format "Program Database (/Zi)" set.
- The dll project has Generate Debug info "Generate Debug Information (/DEBUG)" set.
- Also i have Profile "Yes (/PROFILE)" set for the dll. Not sure what it does.

The .pdb file is generated, placed in the folder of the binary and loaded when starting the program  with the Visual Studio 2017 Perfomance Profiler attached.

- I see some toplevel calls in the dll, but it seems incomplete and
  doesn't reach native C++ code.
- I can step into the native C++ code
  with debugger.
- The debugger tool "Very Sleepy" gives the correct
  output.

A colleague said a spectre fix combined with the fact im using Win7 introduced the problem. (https://superuser.com/questions/1287914/visual-studio-2013-profiler-chrashes-and-system-restarts-reboots)

I'm not sure my problem is related to this...? Have i forgotten some setting?

Comment: In "Performance Explorer", are all three projects listed under the "Targets"?  And right-click each one and make sure that "Collect Samples" is checked.

Answer (score 5):

"Sampling" mode profiling does not work in Win7 after the spectre fix (which you discovered in your link).  I happen to have a win10 machine with vs2017 on which I am developing a C++/CLI dll (with large portions in native code).  On the win10 machine, when I use CPU sampling (starting a C# exe that uses my C++/CLI dll), I get sampling data for the exe and, somehow, for low level calls (like malloc) but not for any of my native code.  I am *confident* this used to work (that is, I was able to get sampling data for my native code).  I can step into my native code debugging with a release mode build.

I, too, wonder if this is a known problem or if I'm just missing a setting somewhere.  I will continue to try to get this working or get an explanation and, if I found one, I'll post back here.

Comment: Same problem here, did anyone manage to make this work ? I find it quite surprising is doesn’t seem to be a more popular issue.